# Why does Ryanair always fill its flight plans with the same remark?

Tags: flight-planning, ryanair

With my current position, I have access to samples of ATC recordings, including all the flight plans received by a [FIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_information_region). Parsing these recordings, I noticed that Ryanair always put the following sentence in both ICAO field F18/RMK and ADEXP field -RMK:

> PAX SCHEDULED FLIGHT CONTACT *+353 IRISH PHONE NUMBER*

Why does Ryanair do that?

*Note:* the field "flight type" is also filled, and contains the letter S for Scheduled, thus my surprise.
*Note2:* +353 is country code for Ireland where Ryanair is based.

Answer (score 4):

It's a contact number for their "HQ". Putting it in the remarks ensures they are easy to get on the phone if necessary for any issue/emergency.

Regarding the redundancy of putting "SCHEDULED" in the remarks - I assume it's for the same reason - ease of locating information.